# Expectations of squared sum question

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, statistical-inference

> I can't seem to figure out why these expectations turn out the way they do, I am currently studying about the Fisher Information. If $X_1,X_2,...,X_n $ are all iid Poission($\lambda$) , then going through the process I reach this stage;

$$\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\mathbb{E}[(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i-n\lambda)^2]$$ Ultimately I am told as the distribution of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$ is Po($\lambda$) that this is equal to $$=\frac{n}{\lambda}$$

My question is when you get an expectation looking like the above how do you go about finding it, regardless of the distribution?

Answer (score 0):

For this specific problem, $\text{E}(X_i) = \lambda$ and $\text{Var}(X_i)=\lambda$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.  This is can be calculated from the Poisson distribution.  Furthermore, the sum of $n$ independent Poisson$(\lambda)$ random variables is
$$
  Z = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim \text{Poisson}(n\lambda).
$$
Hence, $\text{E}\left(Z\right) = \text{Var}\left(Z\right) = n\lambda$.  Therefore,
$$
  \frac{1}{\lambda^2}\text{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i - n\lambda\right)^2 
  = \frac{1}{\lambda^2}\text{E}\left(Z - \text{E}Z\right)^2
  = \frac{1}{\lambda^2}\text{var}\left(Z\right)
  = \frac{n\lambda}{\lambda^2} = \frac{n}{\lambda},
$$
so the expectation above is the variance of $Z$.  So, if you see an expression like
$$
  \text{E}\left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - n\text{E}X \right)^2,
$$
what you have is the variance of the sum.

Comment: Thanks! ok , but how would I find a expectation such as $\mathbb{E}(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2)??$

Comment: The expectation is linear, so you can rewrite this as $\sum_{i=1}^n \text{E}(X_i-\mu)^2$, which is $\sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(X_i)$.  If you know the variance of each $X_i$, then the expectation you wrote down is just the sum of those variances.